# SQL JOIN in 2 tables values and get many values from one column

Tags: sql, join

I Have two tables as follows:

```
Antibiotics                         Patient
id  Name         id   Name  AntibioticA AntibioticB AntibioticC  
1   A             1    John        1          2           3
2   b             2    Jim         4          2           1
3   c
4   d
```

I have the following question: What query I must use in order to take a result like the one below:

```
John A B C (in case id=1)
Jim  D B A (in case id=2)
```

My main problem is that I cannot search many values in the same column.I used JOIN command but it allows me to join only one value of Antibiotics so I take only the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
select P.Name, A1.Name, A2.Name, A3.Name
From Patient p JOIN Antibiotics A1 ON (p.AntibioticA = A1.id) 
JOIN Antibiotics A2 ON (p.AntibioticB = A2.id) 
JOIN Antibiotics A3 ON (p.AntibioticC = A3.id)
```

As pointed out, the Patient table is not in normal form. It would be much easier to work with a table:

```
Patients (PatientName, AntiobioticID)
```

This way, a patient can have any number of antiobiotics not just three (or up to three if NULLs are allowed in the existing Patient table).

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. But they want to be able to assign up to three antibiotics.I dont know why..

Comment: Wow, simple solution with outer join.

Answer (score 0):

And just so we're clear... this table design leaves lots to be desired. Its not in first normal form. What if some patients need only one antibiotic, while another patient needs seven?   An alternative table design...

```
Antibiotics            Patient
AB_id  AB_Name         Patient_Name      AB_id  
1      A               John              1          
2      b               John              2          
3      c               John              3
4      d               Jim               4
                       Jim               2
                       Jim               1
                       Joe               2

SELECT   p.Patient_Name AS 'Name', a.AB_Name AS 'Antibiotics'
FROM     Patient p
  INNER JOIN Antibiotics a ON p.AB_id = a.AB_id
ORDER BY p.Patient_Name

Output:
Name  |  Antibiotics
---------------------
Jim   |  d
Jim   |  b
Jim   |  A
Joe   |  b
John  |  A
John  |  b
John  |  c
```

And to make it really pretty...

```
SELECT   p.Patient_Name AS 'Patient',
         GROUP_CONCAT(a.AB_Name SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'Antibiotics'
FROM     Patient p
INNER JOIN Antibiotics a ON p.AB_id = a.AB_id
GROUP BY p.Patient_Name

Patient   | Antibiotics
---------------------------------------
Jim       |  d, b, A
Joe       |  b
John      |  A, b, c
```

I'm hoping you are a new person to SQL (and that I'm helping you a bit), and not a person trying to use SQL to test a concept from a MongoDB or other non-sql database.  And, hey, I learned something new today... how to make a clumsy SQL query output look a little prettier with the GROUP_CONCAT / GROUP BY addition to my toolbox.  If you are new to SQL, I'd recommend you learn how to design database tables, with a focus on first, second and third normal forms.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Antibiotics (id int, Name nvarchar(10));
insert into Antibiotics values(1, 'a');
insert into Antibiotics values(2, 'b');
insert into Antibiotics values(3, 'c');
insert into Antibiotics values(4, 'd');

create table Patient(id int, Name nvarchar(10), AntibioticA nvarchar(10), AntibioticB nvarchar(10), AntibioticC nvarchar(10));
insert into Patient values(1, 'John', 1, 2, 3);
insert into Patient values(2, 'Jim', 4, 2, 1);

/*

John A B C (in case id=1)
Jim  D B A (in case id=2)

*/

SELECT t.bname,
(SELECT name FROM Antibiotics WHERE id = t.Antibiotica),
(SELECT name FROM Antibiotics WHERE id = t.Antibioticb),
(SELECT name FROM Antibiotics WHERE id = t.Antibioticc)
FROM
(SELECT a.id , a.name AS aname, b.name AS bname, b.Antibiotica, b.Antibioticb, b.Antibioticc
FROM Antibiotics a
     INNER JOIN Patient b
         ON a.id = b.id) t
```

SQLfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e642/1